# admin recovery of deleted email

Tags: email

We have remote sales people using email accounts through our server accessed via C-Panel.
One of them deleted an important email. Is there a way for me as admin to recover that email?

Answer (score 3):

Very unlikely. If C-Panel is involved, the usual mailers that drive mail in such circumstances don't have built in recovery mechanisms. You'd have to dig into backups to get that message back, which is something outside of C-Panel (I believe).